# Android NFC and onNewIntent()

Tags: android, android-intent, nfc

When writing the `onNewIntent(Intent intent)` method in an NFC Activity, is it neccessary/correct to call `super.onNewIntent(intent)` ?

I ask because this [official example](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/nfc.html) includes it:

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    ...
    if (intent != null && NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        Parcelable[] rawMessages =
            intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES);
        if (rawMessages != null) {
            NdefMessage[] messages = new NdefMessage[rawMessages.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < rawMessages.length; i++) {
                messages[i] = (NdefMessage) rawMessages[i];
            }
            // Process the messages array.
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

But this [other official example](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/advanced-nfc.html) doesn't:

```
public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    Tag tagFromIntent = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
    //do something with tagFromIntent
}
```

Presumably, the second example is incomplete (and incorrect) but I would just like to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

Based on official [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent(android.content.Intent)) there's no reason to call `super.onNewIntent(..)`.

As an example you could check `onDestroy()` method [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onDestroy()). It includes next line:

> Derived classes must call through to the super class's implementation
>   of this method. If they do not, an exception will be thrown.

Comment: Thanks. Would there be any harm in calling it?

Comment: @ban-geoengineering Nope. Only 1 useless line of code.

Comment: @ban if that's solve your question, please approve the answer. Thanks in advanced.